# Merging 2 android sqlite queries in a train schedule app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building a android application with sqlite for train schedules. My application requests from the user 2 train stations, to and from and a date (I'm ignoring the date for now). With those I've been trying to do a single query to return all schedules available between those stations on a given day.

My table structure is:

```
stations (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
          name TEXT, 
          central BOOLEAN)

schedule_stations (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                   arrival TEXT, 
                   departure TEXT, 
                   availability INTEGER, 
                   stationID INTEGER, 
                   FOREIGN KEY(stationID) REFERENCES stations(_id))

schedule (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
          trainID INTEGER, 
          day TEXT, 
          scheduleStationId INTEGER, 
          FOREIGN KEY(scheduleStationId) REFERENCES schedule_stations(_id))
```

So far I've been able to devise 2 queries one using the From station given :

```
            c1=db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT s2._id, name, departure, trainID " +
                        "FROM schedule_stations s1 INNER JOIN stations s2 " +
                        "ON s1.stationID = s2._id INNER JOIN schedule s3 " +
                        "ON s3.scheduleStationId = s1._id " +
                        "WHERE stationID=? ", 
                        new String[] {station1+""});
```

This gives me all the departures from the provided From station (station1).

And using the To station I have:

```
            c2=db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT s2._id, name, arrival, trainID " +
                        "FROM schedule_stations s1 INNER JOIN stations s2 " +
                        "ON s1.stationID = s2._id INNER JOIN schedule s3 " +
                        "ON s3.scheduleStationId = s1._id " +
                        "WHERE stationID=? AND trainID IN ("+queryPlaceholders(strlist.size()-1)+")", 
                        strlist.toArray(new String[0]));
```

This gives me all the arrivals to the provided To station that have trainIDs that showed up in first query (to guarantee a connection).

If I output the cursors they seem correct, individually (notice last 3 elements are: Station name | time | trainID):

```
C1: Row: 0, Values: 1; Station A; 08:00; 1
C1: Row: 1, Values: 1; Station A; 12:00; 2
C2: Row: 0, Values: 2; Station B; 09:00; 1
C2: Row: 1, Values: 2; Station B; 13:00; 2
```

What I would like is to somehow merge these in a single query so I end up with only 1 cursor that I can use to populate my listadapter and my view. MergeCursor didn't help because it just added the columns, doesn't link them by the trainID.
I tried using a INNER JOIN and a UNION between the queries but I ran into syntax errors.

Assuming the output above, what I expect from a single query is a cursor giving 2 rows, each row with 2 name stations and 2 dates (arrival/departure) as that is the information I want to show in each row of the android view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT FromSch.trainID,
       FromSt.name,
       FromSchSt.departure,
       ToSt.name,
       ToSchSt.arrival
FROM    stations          FromSt
   JOIN schedule_stations FromSchSt ON FromSt._id = FromSchSt.stationID
   JOIN schedule          FromSch   ON FromSchSt._id = FromSch.scheduleStationId
   JOIN schedule          ToSch     ON FromSch.trainID = ToSch.trainID
                                   AND FromSch.day = ToSch.day
   JOIN schedule_stations ToSchSt   ON ToSch.scheduleStationId = ToSchSt._id
   JOIN stations          ToSt      ON ToSchSt.stationID = ToSt._id
WHERE  FromSt._id = ?
   AND ToSt._id = ?
-- AND FromSch.day = ?
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. I'll test it with a larger data set and report if there are inconsistencies. Only had to do 2 minor change because of sqlite3 and android, I need to also select FromSch._id or it complained there was no column named id and had to rename FromSt.name As name1 so i could fetch the result later into my view.